# Inserting JSON ID key into ng-click directive and then pass that into another controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, angularjs-directive

This section of the app shows the minimal information of a user's task. When they click the "view details" button it will take them to a page that has more information about that specific CAR based on is ID.

Here is a pic to help explain the first part of what I am talking about:

[image]

Here is my angular code: **EDIT** - Added ui-router code

```
angular.module('ngApp', ['ui.router'])
.factory('authInterceptor', authInterceptor)
.constant('API', 'http://myserver.com/ecar/api')
.controller('task', taskData)
.controller('carDetails', carDetails)
.controller('myCars', myCars)

 // ** EDIT ** ADDED MY UI-ROUTER CODE
.config(function($httpProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/cars');      

  $stateProvider

  .state('cars', {
    url: '/cars',
    templateUrl: 'cars.html'
  })

  .state('carDetails', {
    url: '/carDetails',
    templateUrl: 'mycar_details.html',
    controller: 'carDetails'
  })

  .state('taskDetails', {
    url: '/taskDetails',
    templateUrl: 'task_details.html',
    controller: 'taskData'
  })
)}

function carDetails($scope, $http, API) {
  $http.get( API + '/car/**THE CAR ID**' ).
  success(function(data) {
    $scope.details = data;
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

**EDIT** - Button HTML:

```
<a ng-click="" ui-sref="carDetails">View Details</a>
```

As you can see each CAR has its own unique ID (of course). I can display the ID by using:

```
ng-repeat="task in mainTask.Tasks"

{{ task['CAR ID'] }} // in the html
```

But I need this to do two things:

1. When the user clicks the View button I need it to take them to another page titled car_details.html. That page will make use of the "carDetails" controller which will display all the info for the CAR.
2. When a user clicks that same button I need somehow to take that specific ID of that CAR ( {{ task['CAR ID'] }} ) being displayed in that tile and then somehow pass it to the carDetails function in the spot that says:

   $http.get( API + '/car/THE CAR ID' )

Where "THE CAR ID' needs to have the ID passed to it of the CAR who's "view details" button was just clicked. So that when the car_details.html page opens it will have all the correct content loaded for that car.

**EDIT** - The routes work good in the main html file with ui-view. But I just cant figure out how to pass the unique ID from each of the tiles JSON ID key when their respective "view details" button is clicked.

I hope I have been clear enough. Let me know if I haven't and I will try to give you more info.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 commonly accepted ways (that I know of) to handle this. The first, most popular, and most highly recommended way is to use a service or factory. The other is to use the router and routeParams to pass the ID of the card to the details controller.

I have no idea how you plan on displaying your details page (either using the router to navigate to a new page, or a directive to simply hide/show some hidden DOM elements), but a service/factory can be used in BOTH situations, where as the routeParams can only be used in one.

(I also highly recommend you follow, as closely as possible, the angular style guide here: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md if you want to save yourself a lot of headaches)

```
angular.module('ngApp', [])
.service('CarDetailService', CarDetailService)
.controller('task', taskData)
.controller('carDetails', carDetails);

CarDetailService.$inject = ['$http', 'API'];
function CarDetailService($http, API) {
  var CarDetailService = this;
  CarDetailService.setCar = function(carId) {
    CarDetailService.carId = carId;
  };

  CarDetailService.getCar = function() {
    return $http.get(API + "/car/" + CarDetailService.carId);
  };
}

taskData.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'API', 'CarDetailService'];
function taskData($scope, $http, API, CarDetailService) {
  $http.get( API + '/tasks' ).
  success(function(data) {
    $scope.mainTask = data;
    console.log(data);
  });

  $scope.selectCar = function(carId) {
    CarDetailService.setCar(carId);
    $location.url('/car-details-route');  //go to details page
  };
}

carDetails.$inject = ['$scope', 'CarDetailService'];
function carDetails($scope, CarDetailService) {
  CarDetailService.getCar().success(function(details) {
    $scope.details = details;
  });
}
```

And your `ng-repeat` would look somthing like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="task in mainTask.tasks" ng-click="selectCar(task['Car ID'])">
  {{task['Car ID']}}
</div>
```

The service is a singleton, meaning that the id will persist through route changes and controller existences.

The other way, is to use $routeParams. The docs for that are here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

$routeParams allows you to add your ID into the path which is read by the router and passed to the controller:

```
angular.module('ngApp', []).config(function($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider.when('/car-details-route/:carId', {
    controller: 'carDetails',
    templateUrl: 'car-details.html'
  });

})
.controller('task', taskData)
.controller('carDetails', carDetails);


taskData.$inject = ['$scope', '$location'];
function taskData($scope, $location) {
  $http.get( API + '/tasks' ).
  success(function(data) {
    $scope.mainTask = data;
    console.log(data);
  });

  $scope.selectCar = function(carId) {
    $location.path('/car-details-route/'+carId); 
  };
}

carDetails.$inject = ['$scope', 'API', '$routeParams'];
function carDetails($scope, API, $routeParams) {
  $http.get(API + "/cars/" + $routeParams.carId).success(function(details) {
    $scope.details = details;
  });
}
```

Comment: Ok this looks very promising! But I am getting an error. "Error: $injector:unpr / Unknown Provider" -- Unknown provider: CarDetailsServiceProvider <- CarDetailsService <- task. Also I do have ui-router setup and am using "states" in js and "ui-view" in the html

Comment: It looks like I spelled CarDetailsController and CarDetailController. The thing with angular is you really need to be good about checking your spelling or you will see this error a lot.

Comment: I've edited the code so that the spelling of CarDetailController is consistent throughout the example

Comment: This code is meant as an example. Not for you to just plug and run. It's to help you understand how to use a service. That error means that for some reason, angular cannot find your service declaration and has no knowledge of "CarDetailsService" you must use critical thinking to figure out how to resolve the issue

Comment: Ya I forgot to add the service deceleration in the module ( .service('CarDetailService', CarDetailService) ). So the error is gone. I am also using ui-router to route users to the pages I need them to with ui-view in the HTML (see my above edited code). So I changed " $location.url('task_details.html'); " to $state.go('taskDetails'): " but with either of those in there nothing happens. I can see what you code is trying to do I just doesn't know why it doesn't work. It doesn't even route to a page. Also my bad :) but the "taskData" function isn't part of this.

Comment: I also tried moving the $scope.selectCar function in the the carDetails functions but still nothing happens. I am still learning angular and have never tried to do this before which is why I am struggling with this and need so much help. I do apologize.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118958/discussion-between-joelcdoyle-and-agon024).

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="task in mainTask.Tasks">
  <div ng-click="carDetails.getCar( task['CAR ID'] )" > {{ task['CAR ID'] }} </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: explaination:
my thinking is that PO did not know how to properly use ng-click nor that you can send real object and its properties, or that under the ng-repeat you actually have in your scope the repeater object

EDIT2: how to add carID to the request

```
function carDetails($scope, $http, API) {
  $scope.getCar = function(carID){
     $http.get( API + '/car/' + carID ).
       success(function(data) {
          $scope.details = data;
          console.log(data);
   });
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Um. How is this adding the [CAR ID] into the carDetails $http.get request? I need it to be injected into $http.get( API + '/car/**THE CAR ID**' ).    ** THE CAR ID ** is where that data needs to be sent to.

Comment: Hrmm...This still isn't working. Its not even sending a request to the API. here is what the button looks like - <a ng-click="carDetails.func( task['CAR ID'] )" ng-href="task_details.html">View Details</a>

Comment: 1st change carDetail.func to the real function name.     2nd you cant have both a click AND an href on an anchor

Comment: Oops. I don't know why I pasted that in there. I had it correct in my code. And it wasn't inserting anything into the function probably cause of the ng-ref so I did remove that from the link. But how would I pass this into the controller function and send the user to task_details.html (which is where the controller that is storing that ID is being used)?

Comment: my dear its time to make us a big plunker with everything you have/need so we can easier help you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain state and go to a `details` page, I highly recommend using `ui-router`. Which you can learn more about [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

To glean some more detail into how you would do what you want with `ui-router` and using `ui-sref` check out this really helpful Stack with incredible upvotes.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Answer (score 0):

Recommend using **ui-router** for routing

```
$stateProvider
    .state('car.detail', {
        url: "/car/:carId",
        templateUrl: 'car.detail.html',
        controller: function ($stateParams) {
            // If we got here from a url of /car/42
            //You can get car id on detail page by
            console.log($stateParams.carId) //output : 42
        }
    })
```

For View detail button or link use following

```
<div ng-repeat="task in mainTask.Tasks">
  <a ui-sref="car.detail({carId:  task['CAR ID'] })> View Detail </a>
</div>
```

When you click on 'View detail' it is redirect on car detail page 
on car.detail contorller you can get car id from URL by using

```
var carId = $stateParams.carId
```

after get **carId** you can send API call for get car detail

On car detail controller you can create init function like:

```
 $scope.getCar = function(carID){
     $http.get( API + '/car/' + carID ).
       success(function(data) {
          $scope.details = data;
          console.log(data);
   });


$scope.fnInit = function(){
var carId = $stateParams.carId;
$scope.getCar(carId);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are getting the ID in this example from a url. Is that correct?

Comment: I need to get the id from the JSON key "CAR ID" that is being returned from the API. The API returns an array with multiple objects in it. The objects being returned are what is being displayed in the "white tiles" pictured above using ng-repeat. The objects contain the CAR ID key with the ID value. I need to grab that ID (which will be different per tile) by way of the ngClick directive and insert it into the function (which you have done i believe). I just need to get the ID from the JSON key not the url.

Comment: Actually I do see what this code is doing. It is getting the id from the JSON key. But I can't seem to get the thing to work. ABOVE I have edited the code to show the ui-router $states that I was using that work when I use ui-sref. So that (I believe is setup) and when I remove my " .state('carDetails' " route and add your " .state('car.detail' " route I get an error when I click the "view details" button saying "Could not resolve 'car.detail' from state 'cars'". Based on my $stateProvider states the URL is " server.com/ecarapp/dashboard/dashboard.html#/cars ". Is something in my routes wrong?

Comment: can you give me your $stateProvider routing code? 
code like   
**.state('car.detail', {
        url: "/car/:carId",
        templateUrl: 'car.detail.html',
        controller: function ($stateParams) {
            // If we got here from a url of /car/42
            //You can get car id on detail page by
            console.log($stateParams.carId) //output : 42
        }
    }**

Comment: I have updated my code above to show my routing code.

Answer (score 0):

**Please see code comments for understanding**

**Angualr Code**

```
angular.module('ngApp', ['ui.router'])
    .factory('authInterceptor', authInterceptor)
    .constant('API', 'http://myserver.com/ecar/api')
    .controller('taskData', taskData)
    .controller('carDetails', carDetails)
    .controller('myCars', myCars)

    // ** EDIT ** ADDED MY UI-ROUTER CODE
    .config(function ($httpProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/cars');

        $stateProvider
            .state('cars', {
                url: '/cars',
                templateUrl: 'cars.html'
            })

            .state('carDetails', {
                url: '/carDetails/:carId', //:carId use for pass id in URL
                templateUrl: 'mycar_details.html',
                controller: 'carDetails'
            })

            .state('taskDetails', {
                url: '/taskDetails',
                templateUrl: 'task_details.html',
                controller: 'taskData'
            })
    });

/* I think you use following controller for display task list in ng-repeat (ng-repeat="task in mainTask.Tasks")*/
function taskData($scope, $state) {

    /* fnGoToCarDetails function redirect on 'mycar_details.html' page
    * When you redirect on 'mycar_details.html' the URL is look like : "/#/carDetails/48"
    * in URL "12208" is  a car id
    * You can get it in "carDetails" controller by $stateParams (see "carDetails" controller I have write code for it)
    * */
   $scope.fnGoToCarDetails = function(id){
       $state.go('carDetails', {carId: id}) //carDetails is state name which you have declared in routing
   }
}

function carDetails($scope, $http, $stateParams, API) {

    $scope.carID = $stateParams.carId; // ID get from URL parameters


    $scope.fnGetCarDetails = function(carId){
        $http.get(API + '/car/carId').success(function (data) {
            $scope.details = data;
            console.log(data); // you get a car data here
        });
    };

  //call function for get a car detail when page load
  $scope.fnGetCarDetails($scope.carID);

}
```

Suppose Code for task_details.html look like following

```
<!--I think you use "taskData" controller for display  task list in ng-repeat (ng-repeat="task in mainTask.Tasks")-->
<div ng-controller="taskData">
  <div ng-repeat="task in mainTask.Tasks">

    <a ng-click="fnGoToCarDetails( task['CAR ID'])">View Details</a>

    <!--You can also use ui-sref to redirect on 'mycar_details.html' without any function(ng-click) [for it use following code]-->
    <!--<a ui-sref="carDetails({carId: task['CAR ID']})">View Details</a>-->

  </div>
</div>
```

I think above code help you....