# AngularJS - unable to pass ID into another controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

Thanks to the help of JoelCDoyle from a previous question that I asked ([overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624433/inserting-json-id-key-into-ng-click-directive-and-then-pass-that-into-another-co)), I am able to grab an ID from a JSON key value and pass it to another controller in order to append the end a API address being called.

Here is the code that is working from the previous post:

```
CarDetailService.$inject = ['$http', 'API'];
function CarDetailService($http, API) {
  var CarDetailService = this;
  CarDetailService.setCar = function(carId) {
    CarDetailService.carId = carId;
  };

  CarDetailService.getCar = function() {
    return $http.get(API + "/car/" + CarDetailService.carId);
  };
}

myTasks.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'API', 'CarDetailService', '$state'];
function myTasks($scope, $http, API, CarDetailService, $state) {
  $http.get( API + '/tasks' ).
  success(function(data) {
    $scope.mainTask = data;
    console.log(data);
  });

  $scope.selectCar = function(carId) {
    CarDetailService.setCar(carId);
    $state.go('taskDetails');
  };
}


// EDITED
carDetails.$inject = ['$scope', 'CarDetailService', '$http', 'API'];
function carDetails($scope, CarDetailService, $http, API) {
  // console.log('Post injection: ' + CarDetailService.carId);
  CarDetailService.getCar().success(function(details) {
    $scope.details = details;
  });
}
```

now I have been able to add it to a another controller by just copying the code from the other one and changing a few things like so:

```
myCars.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'API', 'CarDetailService', '$state'];
function myCars($scope, $http, API, CarDetailService, $state) {
  $http.get( API + '/car' ).
  success(function(data) {
    $scope.myCars = data;
    console.log(data);
  });

  $scope.selectCar = function(carId) {
    CarDetailService.setCar(carId);
    $state.go('taskDetails');
  };
}
```

But right now I have two other controllers that I need to add it to and I can't seem to get those to work.

**First One** should be as simple as the first two. I just copied the previous one and changed a few things like I did before:

```
observedCars.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'API', 'CarDetailService', '$state'];
function observedCars($scope, $http, API, CarDetailService, $state) {
  $http.get( API + '/car/?observed=true&offset=0&page_size=20' ).
  success(function(data) {
    $scope.observed = data;
    console.log(data);
  });

  $scope.selectCar = function(carId) {
    console.log('Car ID is ' + carId);
    CarDetailService.setCar(carId);
    $state.go('taskDetails');
    console.log( 'Get Car is ' + CarDetailService.carId);
  };
}
```

As you can see I have the output of the id being logged into the console to make sure it is grabbing the ID and it does. It prints in the console the carID and CarDetailService.carId so that tells me that it is grabbing the right id but it is not injecting it into the *carDetails* controller. I am stumped for the most part. I am pretty sure that it has something to do with the original API call from the observedCars controller:

```
 /?observed=true&offset=0&page_size=20
```

But again it still grabs the proper ID bust just doesn't inject it into the *carDetails* controller.

The HTML ng-click references are as so:

```
<div ng-repeat="task in mainTask.Tasks" class="myCar">
    <div class="viewCar"><a ng-click="selectCar(task['CAR ID'])">View Details</a></div>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="car in myCars['My CARs']" class="myCar">
    <div class="viewCar"><a ng-click="selectCar(car['CAR ID'])">View Details</a></div>
</div>

<div dir-paginate="obv in observed['Observed CARs'] | filter:q | itemsPerPage: 5" class="myCar">
    <div class="viewCar"><a ng-click="selectCar(obv['CAR ID'])">View Details</a></div>
</div>
```

**Second One** I can't figure out is my search controller. It does the same thing as the observedCars controller. This one also logs the proper CAR ID in the console but when the state changes it does not load the ID info of the one that it grabbed.

Here is that code:

```
function searchRes($scope, $http, API){

  $scope.$watch('search', function() {
    fetch();
  });

  $scope.currentPage = 1;
  $scope.pageSize = 5;

  function fetch(){
    $http.get(API + "/search/" + $scope.search)
    .then(function(data){ 
      $scope.results = data;
    });
  }

  $scope.select = function(){
    this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length);
  }

  $scope.selectCar = function(carId) {
    console.log('Car ID is ' + carId);
    CarDetailService.setCar(carId);
    $state.go('taskDetails');
    console.log( 'Get Car is ' + CarDetailService.carId);
  };
}
```

Any help is greaaaaatly appreciated!

Comment: are you using route Params or state Params to pass value from one controller to another??

Comment: You should look at the docs for ui-router: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/url-routing. You can pass the id between states easily without going through all that trouble.

Comment: if id is been  used for all controllers, then you use them with rootscope

Comment: inject rootscope - ['$scope', '$http', 'API', 'CarDetailService', '$state','$rootscope']  and store id as $rootscope.id = ID  and use it across all controllers

Comment: http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/QEYoOo

Comment: To make this easier you may need to  look at the original post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624433/inserting-json-id-key-into-ng-click-directive-and-then-pass-that-into-another-co). The carDetails service is working on the other controllers except the observedCars controller and the searchRes controller. The ID is coming from a JSON key value from one API call and when selectCar is run through ng-click it passes the ID to another controller when that runs on the taskDetails page from the state change (and there are around 30 different ID that can be grabbed from this page).

Comment: Please include all details necessary to answer the question, in each question. Questions should stand on their own. Additionally, limit yourself to one question per question.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan This is actually just one question in which I'm letting you know that what is working on all other controllers does not work on these TWO controllers. Additionally I have included all necessary details in order to answer this question (including the original post from a week or so ago in which we got this working with other controllers) so I don't know what more you want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NM. I got it working. It was a user rights access issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have missing code? I think you are supposed to inject the "API" dependency as shown below:

### INCORRECT

```
carDetails.$inject = ['$scope', 'CarDetailService'];
function carDetails($scope, CarDetailService, API) {
```

### CORRECT

```
carDetails.$inject = ['$scope', 'CarDetailService' 'API'];
function carDetails($scope, CarDetailService, API) {
```

Comment: Actually that was my bad. I am injecting the API properly I just screwed up in my original post a few minutes ago. Check my edit up top that is how I am doing it. And it works for the two other controllers just not the observed cars and I can't figure out how to get it to work with the search controller either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass that id to `stateParam` so you can grab it in another `controller`

```
 $scope.selectCar = function(carId) {
    console.log('Car ID is ' + carId);
    CarDetailService.setCar(carId);
    $state.go('taskDetails',{ carId:carId });
    console.log( 'Get Car is ' + CarDetailService.carId);
  };
```

### Important $stateParams

```
controller: function($stateParams){
  $stateParams.contactId  //*** Exists! ***//
}
```

If you don't want to use stateParam and just want to pass id to another controller you can just pass through your service which you use to store id.

```
 CarDetailService.getCarId = function() {
    return CarDetailService.carId;
  };
```

### in your controller

```
  carController.$inject = ['$scope', 'CarDetailService'];
    function observedCars($scope, CarDetailService) {
     function getCarId(){
        return CarDetailService.getCarId;
     }
    }
```

Comment: again I don't want to change what is working on all other controllers except these two. Plus I don't believe this will work since the page has 50 results through ng-repeat. and I need to grab one of those specific 50 IDs on the page when you click the the "view details" button. See the original post from a week or so ago when we finally got it working - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624433/inserting-json-id-key-into-ng-click-directive-and-then-pass-that-into-another-co

Comment: if you don't want to use stateParam then just service to share id between controllers

Comment: That is what I am basically doing. This post is to ask why this is working across all my other controllers except these TWO. The _CarDetailService_ function is grabbing the ID and the injecting that into an API call just fine in all the other controllers.

Comment: it's nothing wrong with your code what i can see just make sure how they are loading i mean if your observedCars controller loading after the carDetails controller then it can not have the id as it's not set yet.
if you print this // console.log('Post injection: ' + CarDetailService.carId); what does it have?

Comment: The carDetails controller is loading last yes.

Comment: and could you print and see what is the context of your service there?

Comment: if I put that in the CarDetailService.getCar it logs " Post injection: 13494 " which is the proper ID of the one I clicked on. Even if I add console.log(API + "/car/" + CarDetailService.carId); it will log " http://myserver.com/ecar/api/car/13494. So I don't know why it wont inject that into the "carDetails" controller like all the other ones do.

Comment: What I mean is have you logged it in carDetails controller and see what in that. If your service was not injected you should have got error. I guess you don't have any errors?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120991/discussion-between-mrjsingh-and-agon024).